# From a web application (Javascript running on browser), Is it possible to detect if any external device is connected through HDMI?

Tags: javascript, hdmi

We are developing a video streaming website and have a business requirement to stop playback, if any external display (e.g. TV) is connected to the PC through HDMI.

Is it possible to check this in javascript?

I tried using [Presentation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Presentation_API) and [Remote Playback API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Remote_Playback_API) supported on browsers, but they seem to work only for "**casting**" and not for simple media "**mirroring**" through HDMI.

The [w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/presentation-api/#interface-presentationavailability) however specifies that the Presentation API is meant for 1-UA (User Agent) mode as well (simple mirroring through HDMI).

Somehow I am not able to use Presentation API to check if any display device is connected through HDMI or not.

Can anyone help me out with my query?

Comment: What if you have a computer which uses HDMI to connects its one and only screen…? What if I connect a DisplayLink display instead, that's fine? DVI? — It really sounds like you're barking up the wrong tree. You're not particularly interested in a specific connector, you're interested in… allowing playback only on… "secure" devices? There's some half-secret CPM video technology built into modern browsers, which is probably what you're looking for then…

Comment: @deceze, Thanks for the quick reply. Indeed this is a workaround, to address a different issue. We are ok to stop playback for 'any' device connected through HDMI, even if it is secure and HDCP compliant.